# Using array map to filter results with if conditional

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dictionary

I am trying to use an array map to filter a object a bit further to prepare it to send to the server to for saving. I can filter to 1 key value, which is great, but I want to take it 1 step further and check them against a boolean inside.

So, right now this is what I have -

```
$scope.appIds = $scope.applicationsHere.map( function(obj){
        if(obj.selected == true){
            return obj.id;
        }
    });
```

This works great for pulling out the id's, however I don't want to push them in this new array if they their selected value == false, so I put a conditional to filter further. This somewhat works, I get an array of id's, but the id's that have .selected == false are still in the array, just with the value of null. So If  I have 4 items in the object and 2 of them are false it looks like this  -

```
 appIds = {id1, id2, null, null};
```

My question is - is there a way to do this without the nulls being put in there. Thanks for reading!

Comment: In JS there's `Array.prototype.filter` method for this purpose.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

You're looking for the `.filter()` function:

```
  $scope.appIds = $scope.applicationsHere.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.selected;
  });
```

That'll produce an array that contains only those objects whose "selected" property is `true` (or truthy).

*edit* sorry I was getting some coffee and I missed the comments - yes, as jAndy noted in a comment, to filter and then pluck out just the "id" values, it'd be:

```
  $scope.appIds = $scope.applicationsHere.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.selected;
  }).map(function(obj) { return obj.id; });
```

Some functional libraries (like [Functional](http://osteele.com/sources/javascript/functional/), which in my opinion doesn't get enough love) have a `.pluck()` function to extract property values from a list of objects, but native JavaScript has a pretty lean set of such tools.

Comment: Can I then turn appids into an arra of just ids and not the full object? thanks for your help!

Comment: @user3201696 You would need to chain a `.map()` after the filter, definitely possible.

Comment: @jAndy awesome, thanks!! Is there somewhere I can see an example, as I'm sure how to chain the 2 together. Would I just do the map inside this filter after the return?

Comment: @user3201696 it would pretty much look like `.filter(function(obj) { return obj.selected; }).map(function(obj) { return obj.id1 });` That would create a new array which only contains the values of the `id1` properties.

Comment: Great answers, thank you for your help guys. Quick follow up question, can you use these methods to do the reverse of this. So when I get the array back can these methods be used to compare the id array to the object to set the .selected on the object to true (they are all false be default when landing)? My initial idea is to double loop and compare the ids to the ids in the object, but I don't think it is the best method. Thanks again!

Comment: @user3201696 well the opposite process would be a little more involved; there's no similar function that would directly support that, but you could use `.forEach()` to iterate through the list and test whether each object's id is in another list of values with `.indexOf()`.

Comment: +2 for getting coffee!

Answer (score 34):

You should use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to do this. I did do a [little JS perf test](https://jsperf.com/filter-map-vs-reduce-concat-vs-reduce-push/) to verify that this is more performant than doing a `.filter` + `.map`.

```
$scope.appIds = $scope.applicationsHere.reduce(function(ids, obj){
    if(obj.selected === true){
        ids.push(obj.id);
    }
    return ids;
}, []);
```

Just for the sake of clarity, here's the sample `.reduce` I used in the JSPerf test:

```js
  var things = [
    {id: 1, selected: true},
    {id: 2, selected: true},
    {id: 3, selected: true},
    {id: 4, selected: true},
    {id: 5, selected: false},
    {id: 6, selected: true},
    {id: 7, selected: false},
    {id: 8, selected: true},
    {id: 9, selected: false},
    {id: 10, selected: true},
  ];
  
   
var ids = things.reduce((ids, thing) => {
  if (thing.selected) {
    ids.push(thing.id);
  }
  return ids;
}, []);

console.log(ids)
```

---

**EDIT 1**

Note, As of 2/2018 *Reduce + Push* is fastest in Chrome and Edge, but slower than *Filter + Map* in Firefox

Comment: @DanMandel   is possible to stop pushing element first time pushed.. i meant  only one value should printed on console..?

Comment: @SivaprakashD do you mean you want to find the first instance where this is true? you could `var id = things.find(thing => thing.selected)` and it would stop after it finds the first instance https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find. Or use similar `.some` method to just get a true/false "does this object live in this array"

Comment: @JustinL. Thanks for the reply and i solved this form another Stack overflow question....

Comment: @DanMandel - How can filter + map be O(n^2) ? It will be O(2n) I think, which is basically O(n)

Comment: @DanMandel filter + map is definitely O(n) not n².

Comment: It is almost always safer to provide initialValue in reduce

Answer (score 22):

You could use [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap). It can filter and map in one.

```
$scope.appIds = $scope.applicationsHere.flatMap(obj => obj.selected ? obj.id : [])
```

Answer (score 8):

Simple solution

```
SomeArrayValues.filter(x=> x.id !== idNameDetailsColorDto.id).map(ids => (ids.id))
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's some info if someone comes upon this in 2019.

I think reduce vs map + filter might be somewhat dependent on what you need to loop through. Not sure on this but reduce does seem to be slower.

One thing is for sure - if you're looking for performance improvements the way you write the code is extremely important!

[Here a JS perf test](https://jsperf.com/filter-vs-map-order-vs-reduce) that shows the massive improvements when typing out the code fully rather than checking for "falsey" values (e.g. `if (string) {...}`) or returning "falsey" values where a boolean is expected.

Hope this helps someone