# Map and filter an array at the same time

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects that I want to iterate over to produce a new filtered array. But also, I need to filter out some of the objects from the new array depending of a parameter. I'm trying this:

```
function renderOptions(options) {
    return options.map(function (option) {
        if (!option.assigned) {
            return (someNewObject);
        }
    });   
}
```

Is that a good approach? Is there a better method? I'm open to use any library such as lodash.

Comment: what about an "object.keys" approach? https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/keys

Comment: Use reduce : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reduce

Comment: `.reduce()` is definitely faster than doing a `.filter(...).map(...)` which I've seen suggested elsewhere. I set up a JSPerf Test to demonstrate https://stackoverflow.com/a/47877054/2379922

Answer (score 432, accepted):

You should use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for this.

```js
var options = [
  { name: 'One', assigned: true }, 
  { name: 'Two', assigned: false }, 
  { name: 'Three', assigned: true }, 
];

var reduced = options.reduce(function(filtered, option) {
  if (option.assigned) {
     var someNewValue = { name: option.name, newProperty: 'Foo' }
     filtered.push(someNewValue);
  }
  return filtered;
}, []);

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(reduced);
```

```html
<h1>Only assigned options</h1>
<pre id="output"> </pre>
```

---

Alternatively, the reducer can be a pure function, like this

```js
var reduced = options.reduce(function(result, option) {
  if (option.assigned) {
    return result.concat({
      name: option.name,
      newProperty: 'Foo'
    });
  }
  return result;
}, []);
```

Comment: For me, the first arg, `filtered` is an object. so `filtered.push` is undefined for me.

Comment: I also had an issue with `filtered` being an object. This was because I wasn't passing in the "initial value" - the empty array (`[]`) after the reduce function.

e.g. incorrect

 `var reduced = options.reduce(function(filtered, option) {
...
});`

correct

   `var reduced = options.reduce(function(filtered, option) {
...
}, []);`

Comment: There is no reason for `reduce` here, you could just as well use `forEach` since in every iteration you change array `filtered` and thus it is not pure functional. It would be event more readable and compact.

Comment: @Marko I introduced a pure reducer as well. PTAL.

Comment: Yap that is pure now. +1 for your effort. Not that I'm pure functional programming advocate, far from that, I just couldn't see the point :) But actually I have used your trick after seeing it, because it came so handy in the given situation. But for this task you might want to take a look at flatMap function, I think it came into standard after you made your answer (also for that reason may be unsupported by some browsers). It should be more performant since concatenating arrays like this makes O(n^2) task out of O(n) task.

Comment: @Marko `flatMap` cannot be used here, as it would not allow us to filter. Unless, we return an empty array in that case. That would not make things easy for the reader I believe.

Comment: Maybe you're right about readability, but returning empty array is just what I had in mind, it's completely legal use case.

Answer (score 197):

Since 2019, [Array.prototype.flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#For_adding_and_removing_items_during_a_map) is good option.

```
options.flatMap(o => o.assigned ? [o.name] : []);
```

---

From the MDN page linked above:

> `flatMap` can be used as a way to add and remove items (modify the
>   number of items) during a map. In other words, it allows you to map
>   many items to many items (by handling each input item separately),
>   rather than always one-to-one. In this sense, it works like the
>   opposite of filter. Simply return a 1-element array to keep the item,
>   a multiple-element array to add items, or a 0-element array to remove
>   the item.

Comment: How does this compare in term of performance to using 2 loops (by calling array.filter and array.map individually)?

Comment: I compared using jsbench.me and jsben.ch and got very different results. First time flatMap was like 5 times slower, second time it was like 2 times faster. So I don't know how to benchmark it.

Comment: Maybe it's because I have more OO experience, but this answer seems more intuitive than `reduce` to me.

Comment: body.files.flatMap(file => file?.file ?? []) // can be cleaner if you don't need a ternary

Comment: Even nicer with ES6 destructuring: `options.flatMap(({assigned, name}) => assigned ? [name] : []);`

Comment: Instead of returning a "1-element array to keep the item", you can also just return the item itself, right?

Answer (score 73):

With ES6 you can do it very short:

`options.filter(opt => !opt.assigned).map(opt => someNewObject)`

Comment: @hogan but this is the correct answer ( may not be optimal solution ) to the original query

Comment: @vikramvi thank you for your note. The thing is, we can achieve the same things with tons of ways and I´d prefer the best one.

Comment: This is not entierly correct, because here you are loosing the index in which the values where initialy positioned, and that information can be really useful when running the map fn.

Comment: this way is good
but this question is **Map and filter an array at the same time**
best way is `options.reduce(res,options....`
answer @Zuker

Answer (score 62):

Use reduce, Luke!

```
function renderOptions(options) {
    return options.reduce(function (res, option) {
        if (!option.assigned) {
            res.push(someNewObject);
        }
        return res;
    }, []);   
}
```

Answer (score 22):

I'd make a comment, but I don't have the required reputation. A small improvement to Maxim Kuzmin's otherwise very good answer to make it more efficient:

```js
const options = [
  { name: 'One', assigned: true }, 
  { name: 'Two', assigned: false }, 
  { name: 'Three', assigned: true }, 
];

const filtered = options
  .reduce((result, { name, assigned }) => assigned ? result.push(name) && result : result, []);

console.log(filtered);
```

**Explanation**

Instead of spreading the entire result over and over for each iteration, we only append to the array, and only when there's actually a value to insert.

Comment: `.concat()` returns a new array, it's effectively the same as spreading the old array and new item into a new array, [MDN here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat). You want to use `.push()` to "append" as you described.

Comment: @MarceDev ah you're right, thanks. Will update my answer to do that. The syntax then becomes a little bit weird because push does not return the array.

Answer (score 20):

One line `reduce` with ES6 fancy [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) is here!

```js
var options = [
  { name: 'One', assigned: true }, 
  { name: 'Two', assigned: false }, 
  { name: 'Three', assigned: true }, 
];

const filtered = options
  .reduce((result, {name, assigned}) => [...result, ...assigned ? [name] : []], []);

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Really nice @Maxim! I upvote this! But... on each element added, it has to spread all elements in `result`... is like `filter(assigned).map(name)` solution

Comment: Nice one. It took me a sec to realise what was going on with `...assigned ? [name] : []` - it may be more readable as `...(assigned ? [name] : [])`

Comment: This seems inefficient...

Answer (score 9):

At some point, isn't it easier(or just as easy) to use a `forEach`

```js
var options = [
  { name: 'One', assigned: true }, 
  { name: 'Two', assigned: false }, 
  { name: 'Three', assigned: true }, 
];

var reduced = []
options.forEach(function(option) {
  if (option.assigned) {
     var someNewValue = { name: option.name, newProperty: 'Foo' }
     reduced.push(someNewValue);
  }
});

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(reduced);
```

```html
<h1>Only assigned options</h1>
<pre id="output"> </pre>
```

However it would be nice if there was a `malter()` or `fap()` function that combines the `map` and `filter` functions. It would work like a filter, except instead of returning true or false, it would return any object or a null/undefined.

Comment: You might want to check your memes... ;-)

Comment: But then you wouldn't get to show off your 1 line of 133t JS that no one but you understands.

Comment: those names are golden, you should file a proposal to TC39

Answer (score 8):

Use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
function renderOptions(options) {
    return options.filter(function(option){
        return !option.assigned;
    }).map(function (option) {
        return (someNewObject);
    });   
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work very well if the value you want is computed in the course of doing the filter; you have to duplicate that part of the code.

Answer (score 7):

I optimized the answers with the following points:

1. Rewriting `if (cond) { stmt; }` as `cond && stmt;`
2. Use ES6 [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

I'll present two solutions, one using [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), the other using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

**Solution 1: Using forEach**

The solution works by using `forEach` to iterate through every element. Then, in the body of the `forEach` loop, we have the conditional to act as a filter and it determines whether we are going to append something to the result array.

```js
const options = [
  { name: 'One', assigned: true }, 
  { name: 'Two', assigned: false }, 
  { name: 'Three', assigned: true }, 
];
const reduced = [ ];
options.forEach(o => {
  o.assigned && reduced.push( { name: o.name, newProperty: 'Foo' } );
} );
console.log(reduced);
```

**Solution 2: Using reduce**

This solution uses `Array.prototype.reduce` instead of `forEach` to iterate through the array. It recognizes the fact that `reduce` has both an initializer and a looping mechanism built in. Other than that, this solution is more or less the same as the `forEach` solution, so, the difference comes down to cosmetic syntax sugar.

```js
const options = [
  { name: 'One', assigned: true }, 
  { name: 'Two', assigned: false }, 
  { name: 'Three', assigned: true }, 
];
const reduced = options.reduce((a, o) => {
  o.assigned && a.push( { name: o.name, newProperty: 'Foo' } );
  return a;
}, [ ] );
console.log(reduced);
```

I leave it up to you to decide which solution to go for.

Comment: Why on earth would you use `cond && stmt;`? This is much more difficult to read and offers no benefits at all.

Answer (score 4):

I've covert these great answers into utility functions and I'd like to share them:

**Example**: filter only odd numbers and increment it

- e.g. `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` -filter-> `[1, 3, 5]` -map-> `[2, 4, 6]`

Normally you'd do it like this with `filter` and `map`

```
const inputArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const filterOddPlusOne = inputArray.filter((item) => item % 2).map((item) => item + 1); // [ 2, 4, 6 ]
```

---

##### Using `reduce`

```
const filterMap = <TSource, TTarget>(
  items: TSource[],
  filterFn: (item: TSource) => boolean,
  mapFn: (item: TSource) => TTarget
) =>
  items.reduce((acc, cur): TTarget[] => {
    if (filterFn(cur)) return [...acc, mapFn(cur)];
    return acc;
  }, [] as TTarget[]);
```

##### Using `flatMap`

```
const filterMap = <TSource, TTarget>(
  items: TSource[],
  filterFn: (item: TSource) => boolean,
  mapFn: (item: TSource) => TTarget
) => items.flatMap((item) => (filterFn(item) ? [mapFn(item)] : []));
```

##### Usage (same for both `reduce` and `flatMap` solution):

```
const inputArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const filterOddPlusOne = filterMap(
  inputArray,
  (item) => item % 2, // Filter only odd numbers
  (item) => item + 1 // Increment each number
); // [ 2, 4, 6 ]
```

---

#### JavaScript version

The above codes are in TypeScript but the question asks about JavaScript. So, I've remove all the generics and types for you:

```js
const filterMap = (items, filterFn, mapFn) =>
  items.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    if (filterFn(cur)) return [...acc, mapFn(cur)];
    return acc;
  }, []);
```

```js
const filterMap = (items, filterFn, mapFn) =>
  items.flatMap((item) => (filterFn(item) ? [mapFn(item)] : []));
```

Answer (score 3):

Using reduce, you can do this in one Array.prototype function. This will fetch all even numbers from an array.

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

var brr = arr.reduce((c, n) => {
  if (n % 2 !== 0) {
    return c;
  }
  c.push(n);
  return c;
}, []);

document.getElementById('mypre').innerHTML = brr.toString();
```

```html
<h1>Get all even numbers</h1>
<pre id="mypre"> </pre>
```

You can use the same method and generalize it for your objects, like this.

```
var arr = options.reduce(function(c,n){
  if(somecondition) {return c;}
  c.push(n);
  return c;
}, []);
```

`arr` will now contain the filtered objects.

Answer (score 2):

Direct use of `.reduce` can be hard to read, so I'd recommend creating a function that generates the reducer for you:

```js
function mapfilter(mapper) {
  return (acc, val) => {
    const mapped = mapper(val);
    if (mapped !== false)
      acc.push(mapped);
    return acc;
  };
}
```

Use it like so:

```js
const words = "Map and filter an array #javascript #arrays";
const tags = words.split(' ')
  .reduce(mapfilter(word => word.startsWith('#') && word.slice(1)), []);
console.log(tags);  // ['javascript', 'arrays'];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) with an arrow function is a single line of code

```js
const options = [
  { name: 'One', assigned: true }, 
  { name: 'Two', assigned: false }, 
  { name: 'Three', assigned: true }, 
];

const reduced = options.reduce((result, option) => option.assigned ? result.concat({ name: option.name, newProperty: 'Foo' }) : result, []);

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(reduced);
```

```html
<h1>Only assigned options</h1>
<pre id="output"> </pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way of doing `filter` + `map` at once is to process data as a generic iterable, and do both things at once. In this case, you will end up going through data once, at most.

The example below is using [iter-ops](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops) library, and doing exactly that:

```
import {pipe, filter, map} from 'iter-ops';

const i = pipe(
    inputArray,
    filter(value => value === 123), // filter on whatever key you want
    map(value => /* any mapping here*/) // remap data as you like
);

// i = iterable that can be processed further;

console.log([...i]); //=> list of new objects
```

Above, I was saying `at most`, because if you apply further logic to the iterable result, like limit the number of mapped items, for example, you will end up iterating through your list of objects even less than once:

```
const i = pipe(
    inputArray,
    filter(value => value === 123), // filter on whatever key you want
    map(value => /* any mapping here*/), // remap as you like
    take(10) // take up to 10 items only
);
```

Above, we limit iteration further, to stop once 10 resulting items have been generated, and so we are iterating through data less than once. That's as efficient as it gets.

**UPDATE**

I was asked to add to the answer why this solution is more efficient than `reduce`, and so here it is...

Array's `reduce` is a finite operation, which goes through the complete set of data, in order to produce the result. So when you need to do further processing on that output data, you will end up producing a new iteration sequence, and so on.

When you have a complex business logic to be applied to a sequence/iterable, it is always much more efficient to chain that logic, while iterating through the sequence just once. In many cases, you will end up doing complex processing on a sequence, without going through the complete set of data even once. That's the efficiency of iterable data processing.

P.S. I'm the author of the aforesaid library.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const options = [
  { name: 'One', assigned: true }, 
  { name: 'Two', assigned: false }, 
  { name: 'Three', assigned: true }, 
];

const filtered = options
  .reduce((result, { name, assigned }) => assigned ? result.push(name) && result : result, []);

console.log(filtered);
```

Perfect, this code complete my entire function and works fine.
Just one thing, for the part in
assigned ? result.push(name) && result

what it's the purpose for that '&& result' ?
:s

thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO.  Please do not post questions as an answer.  FYI: The `&& result` usually returns `result` because `result.push(name)` returns `name`, and `name` happens to be "truish" here.  However if `name` happens to be "falsish" (like in `{Name:0, assigned:true }` (for somebody called `0` (zero), or `''` because the Name is not available) the code fails, because it returns something falsey instead of `result`!  So better replace `result.push(name) && result` with `(result.push(name), result)` here.  This also has the same number of characters (needs 1 more when minified).

Answer (score 0):

Hey I've just worked on this project and wanted to share my solution based on Array.prototype.flatMap() in MDN docs:

```js
const places=[{latitude:40,longitude:1},{latitude:41,longitude:2},{latitude:44,longitude:2},{latitude:NaN,longitude:NaN},{latitude:45,longitude:4},{latitude:48,longitude:3},{latitude:44,longitude:5},{latitude:39,longitude:13},{latitude:40,longitude:8},{latitude:38,longitude:4}];

let items = places?.map((place) => [{
  latitude: (place.latitude),

  longitude: (place.longitude),
}, ]);

console.log("Items: ", items);

//Remove elements with NaN latitude and longitude

let newItems = places?.flatMap((o) =>
  Number(o.longitude, o.latitude) ?
  {
    lng: Number(o.longitude),
    lat: Number(o.latitude)
  } :
  []
);

console.log("Coordinates after NaN values removed: ", newItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

Same approach as the top answers, using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), but with updated ES6 syntax, and TypeScript typings, as a generic utility function:

```
function filterThenMap<T>(l: T[], predicate: (el: T) => boolean, transform: (el: T) => T) {
  return l.reduce((res: T[], el) => {
    if (predicate(el)) {
      res.push(transform(el));
    }
    return res;
  }, []);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sigh.  Many nice ideas, but nothing fits to what I need.

What I need is:

- A single function for both, map and filter
- filtering is done according to the returned value
- Being able to map all possible values, even true, false, void 0 (aka: undefined) etc.
- I want to be able to use iterables, not just something like an Array which accidentally happens to have a `.length` attribute
- such that I can stop the iteration early

Here is a solution (ES13/ES2022) for this:

```js
'use strict';

function* mapFilter(iter, cb, thisarg)
{
  let stop;
  const guard = _ => (stop=1) && _;
  for (const _ of iter)
    {
      const v = cb.call(thisarg, _, guard);
      if (v !== guard)
        yield v;
      if (stop) break;
    }
}

async function* asyncMapFilter(iter, cb, thisarg)
{
  let stop;
  const guard = _ => (stop=1) && _;
  for await (const _ of iter)
    {
      const v = await cb.call(thisarg, _, guard);
      if (v !== guard)
        yield v;
      if (stop) break;
    }
}

const agents = [
  { name: 'Emma',    assigned: false },
  { name: 'Felix',   assigned: true, assignment:"Mr. Big" },
  { name: 'Harry',   assigned: false },
  { name: 'James',   assigned: true, assignment:"Blofeld" },
  { name: 'Phil',    assigned: false },
  { name: 'Tony',    assigned: false },
  { name: 'Maxwell', assigned: false },
];

const afm = (...a) => Array.from(mapFilter(...a));
const mkiter = function*(...a) { for (const _ of a) yield* _; }

const inAction = () => afm(agents, (agent,_) => agent.assigned ? agent.name : _);
const freeAgents = () => afm(agents, (agent,_) => agent.assigned ? _ : agent.name);
const assignOne = villain => afm(agents, (agent,_) =>
  agent.assigned ? _ : _(agent, agent.assigned = true, agent.assignment = villain)
  )[0];
const assignMany = villains =>
  {
    const iter = mkiter(villains);
    let villain = iter.next();
    return afm(agents, (agent,_) => villain.done ? _(_) :
      agent.assigned ? _ : (agent.assigned = true, agent.assignment = villain.value, villain=iter.next(), agent)
      );
  }

console.log({inActionBefore:inAction(),freeAgentsBefore:freeAgents()});
console.log({newAssigned:assignOne('DeWynter')});
console.log({inActionNow:inAction()});
console.log({moreAssigned:assignMany(['Egan','Thor','Loki'])});
console.log({inActionAfter:inAction(),freeAgentsAfter:freeAgents()});
```

If you are puzzled, the callback function gets two parameters:

- The current element as the first parameter
- And as a second parameter a "guard" value (written as `_` in the example above) to express `ignore` and `stop`

  - If the guard is returned literally, the current element is ignored (filtered)
- If the guard is called as a function instead, the iteration stops.
- The (first) argument to the guard (`x` like in `_(x)`) is passed out again, so you can use it conveniently in a return statement

  - Hence if you want to stop and ignore the element at the same time, you must write `return _(_)`
  - as `return _()` would pass `void 0` as the element

This all might look a bit complex, but as you can see, it makes things short and therefor is very readable after you get accustomed to it.

Notes:

- `afm()` and `mkiter()` are only there to improve readability.  YMMV
- If you want to be able to stop early, you need iterators.  I did not find a better way than `mkiter()` to translate anything, which is iterable, into an iterator.
- `assignMany` iterates 1 too far in the agents.  The code complexity rises a lot (you need to test for `villain.done` before you call `afm()` and also test it again after assignment), if you want to skip this superfluous iteration.  To implement that is left as an exercise to the reader. ;)

Spoiler: [Harry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dempsey_and_Makepeace)