# FlatMap vs Reduce for mapping and filtering - is one recommended over the other?

Tags: javascript, arrays

According to [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34398279/map-and-filter-an-array-at-the-same-time), `flatMap` or `reduce` are recommended when one needs to map and filter on an array of objects, especially if they want to avoid looping through the collection multiple times.  Personally, I prefer using `flatMap` as I think it is easier to read, but that is entirely subjective of course.  Aside from browser compatibility issues for `flatMap`, is one method generally recommended or beneficial over the other (perhaps because of, but not limited to, reasons of performance or readability)?

Update:  Here is an example from the referenced answer of flatMap filtering:

```js
var options = [{
    name: 'One',
    assigned: true
  },
  {
    name: 'Two',
    assigned: false
  },
  {
    name: 'Three',
    assigned: true
  },
];

var assignees = options.flatMap((o) => (o.assigned ? [o.name] : []));
console.log(assignees);

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(assignees);
```

```html
<h1>Only assigned options</h1>
<pre id="output"> </pre>
```

Comment: If there is a problem with my question let me know and I will try to fix it.  Downvoting without any context is not helping me answer my question.

Comment: You cannot filter anything with flatMap. flatmap is the same as map followed by flat. Reduce is not recommended in most cases because it's hard to read.

Comment: @Konowy Actually you can use flatMap to filter.  I updated my question with an example of this in action.

Comment: I don't see the example?

Comment: I got interrupted earlier while I was in the middle of writing it.  It's added now @KonradLinkowski

Comment: Code clarity is always important, especially for maintenance and multiple developers. It's not super clear that your `flatMap` is performing a reduce operation and due to the two-stage nature of `flatMap`, it may not be performant. At least with `reduce`, the intention would be clearer `options.reduce((a, o) => (o.assigned && a.push(o.name), a), [])`

Comment: You are misusing `flatMap` in this example. You don't want to flat anything here. .filter.map is more convenient  here,

Comment: You can check the performance here https://jsben.ch/B2epC but it really doesn't matter if you are not doing millions of operations per second.

Comment: A good example of flatMap btw:
`["it's Sunny in", "", "California"].flatMap(x => x.split(" "));` - splits all words into one array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither actually. For mapping and filtering, your should use `map` and `filter`:

```
var assignees = options.filter(o => o.assigned).map(o => o.name);
```

Much simpler and more readable, it directly expresses your intent. Nothing beats that on clarity.

If you care about performance, always benchmark to see the actual impact on your real-world case - but don't prematurely optimise.

Comment: A filter followed by a map should be done with a reduce in a single iteration rather than two iterations.

Comment: @AdrianBrand it rather should be done using iterators if you cared about a single pass, but I doubt performance matters in most cases. If you know that it does, you'd do a benchmark anyway and probably use a plain loop instead of some `reduce` with a side-effect.

Comment: What is the side effect?

Comment: @AdrianBrand In the code from your answer, `push` would be a side effect for example. I recommend not to mix that with functional approaches.

Comment: Modifying an accumulator cannot be considered a side effect as it does not bleed out of the function, a function is considered pure if it always gives the same output from the same input. Hence no side  effect.

Comment: @AdrianBrand It might not bleed out of the `reduce` call, but it does bleed out of the callback function which makes *that* impure. I see absolutely no benefit over `const assignees = []; for (const item of options) if (item.assigned) assignees.push(item);`

Comment: @Bergi One of my intentions was to avoid looping through the array multiple times as you have to do with map and filter.  I'll update my question to make this clearer.

Comment: @LockettKs But why? There's nothing wrong with it especially if the array is small or the filter is highly selective. Or use an [iterator helpers](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers) polyfill and write `options.values().filter(o => o.assigned).map(o => o.name).toArray()`.

Comment: Look at the sidebar, there is a question with 226 upvotes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34398279/map-and-filter-an-array-at-the-same-time?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @AdrianBrand That's the question that the OP had linked, yes. Not sure what you mean to imply by pointing to an answer with 226 upvotes?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what exactly you want to do with each item, [pushing to a reduce accumulator is generally going to be much faster](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/ShowResult/469112), [especially if your array ends up expanding](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/ShowResult/469110). As many will point out though, unless you're working with big data, the increase in performance is usually not worth making your code less readable.

To choose between the two you mention, I would still use the reduce option, since to me it's actually the clearest about what's happening in your example. Reduce is all about digesting arrays and giving you back the nutrient results you need.

```js
var options = [
  { name: 'One', assigned: true },
  { name: 'Two', assigned: false },
  { name: 'Three', assigned: true },
];

console.time();
var assignees = options.reduce((a, o) => (o.assigned && a.push(o.name), a), []);
console.timeEnd();
console.log(assignees);
```

Two things to note about the above code in case you're having difficulty parsing it:

- The && short-circuit operator here returns o.assigned if falsy or moves on and returns the evaluated push if truthy.
- The , (comma operator) tells the runtime to complete the previous expression and then return what comes after, which is the now mutated variable a. Wrapping it all in brackets is necessary so js knows the comma is part of the arrow function, not a separator.

To me, the above is clear and easy to read, but it can be difficult if you're not properly familiar with those two operators. You can make it clearer and remove the mutation done with push (some prefer to avoid mutations at all costs, even when neatly contained in a single call) by returning `o.assigned ? a.concat([o.name]) : a` instead, but this will exponentially kill the performance and you can easily run out of memory slots as you scale up. The spread operator a la `[...a, o.name]` is even worse. Never use either of these with reduce.

For flatMap, removing empty elements of sparse arrays is simply a side-effect of using `flat` and by extension `flatMap`, when its real purpose is to spread nested arrays into the parent. So using it without a multi-dimensional array, especially with the performance hit, does not make much sense to me even though it's quite common. Where it would make sense is something like the following:

```js
var options = [
  { names: ['One', 'Two', 'Three'], assigned: true },
  { names: ['Four', 'Five', 'Six'], assigned: false },
  { names: ['Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine'], assigned: true },
];

console.time();
var assignees = options.flatMap((o) => (o.assigned) ? o.names : []);
console.timeEnd();
console.log(assignees);
```

If you used reduce for the above, you'd either need to explicitly use the spread operator like so: `a.push(...o.names)`, or resort to a forEach like this: `o.names.forEach(name => a.push(name))`. (Yes, there are worse options, too.) It should be obvious that both these options are kludgy compared to `flatMap` in this case. You could of course just add the `.flat()` to the end of `.filter(...).map(...)`, but that's exactly what `flatMap` is meant to replace, hence its elegance here.

Of course, if there's a possibility that you will be using the filtered list more than once, it may be better to `filter` your options first and then run `map` or whatever you need on the filtered list like @Bergi shows in his answer. If your needs are simple enough, though, another option is to just roll your own function making use of a for loop; then you can name it as semantically as you like. (Running the loop directly rather than setting up a function should be quicker, but you lose flexibility.) I've included all four options with basic benchmarks below:

```js
var options = Array.from({length:1000000}, (v, i) => ({
  name: String(i),
  assigned: Math.random() < 0.5
}));

function getAssignees(list) {
  var assignees = [];
  for (var o of list) if (o.assigned) assignees.push(o.name);
  return assignees;
}

console.time('a');
var assigneesA = options.reduce((a, o) => (o.assigned && a.push(o.name), a), []);
console.timeEnd('a');

console.time('b');
var assigneesB = options.flatMap((o) => (o.assigned) ? [o.name] : []);
console.timeEnd('b');

console.time('c');
var assigneesC = getAssignees(options);
console.timeEnd('c');

console.time('d');
var assigneesD = options.filter(o => o.assigned).map(o => o.name);
console.timeEnd('d');
```

If you run the above enough times, you should notice two things:

1. Depending on your OS & browser, `reduce` is usually fastest but occasionally taken over by the simple loop, `filter`+`map` follows closely behind in performance and `flatMap` is always the slowest option.
2. It takes a million records to really see any appreciable difference in speed, and even then we're looking at milliseconds, so it's seldom worth worrying about.

What you should be thinking about is how the rest of your code is structured, where and how often you need to run something like this, and what will make your intentions clearest. @Bergi makes a good case for `filter`+`map` here as it's certainly the cleanest, clearest and easiest to read, but it's two-pass rather than one and learning how to use reduce properly doesn't hurt. You may, after all, end up needing it down the road for more complex and performance-sensitive transformations of your data.

Comment: Well if you want to avoid `flatMap` because of performance, there's no reason to use an unreadable `reduce` callback expression with side effects. Write an idiomatic simple loop, [it's even faster](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/27789/0/flatmap-vs-reduce-vs-loop-filtering-performance)!

Comment: @Bergi A simple loop is indeed the most straigtforward in this example, but as mentioned in my answer, I didn't just choose it for speed. I chose it over flatMap as the question was one or the other, and reduce is not just more performant but also subjectively more readable to me in this scenario. It's also more concise than a simple loop which can be useful, regardless of its functional purity. It also looks like the simple loop [isn't actually faster on all machines](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/ShowResult/469178).

Answer (score 0):

I would use a reduce in this case.

```js
var options = [{
    name: 'One',
    assigned: true
  },
  {
    name: 'Two',
    assigned: false
  },
  {
    name: 'Three',
    assigned: true
  },
];

var assignees = options.reduce((results, item) => {
  if (item.assigned) {
    results.push(item.name);
  }
  return results;
}, []);
console.log(assignees);
```

Comment: `var assignees = options.reduce((results, item) => ([...results, item]), [])` - more functional approach

Comment: I used to use spread on the accumulator until I did a performance test on it, for both arrays and objects it is about 3 orders of magnitude worse. Over 1000 times slower. I still use spread for creating new objects but avoid it in reduces.

Comment: Do you mind annotating why you would use it in this case?