# How to filter nested array in javascript with values from array to make it work with single values as well?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I came up with an example from another topic which can filter nested array from another array where filter values stored.

Interestingly when there is single element in array,it doesnt work well.

```
const data = [
    {
        "guid": "j5Dc9Z",
        "courses": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "foo"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "guid": "a5gdfS",
        "courses": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "bar"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "foo"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "guid": "jHab6i",
        "courses": [
            {
                "id": 7,
                "name": "foobar"
            }
        ]
    }
];

const courses = [3];
const r = data.filter(d => d.courses.every(c => courses.includes(c.id)));
console.log(r);
```

in case of my example,we are supposed to see two 3 but instead it gives us first one.How can I filter this nested array with multiple values or single?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking for ALL/EVERY object to have id == 3 here, but what you want is to have ANY/SOME of the objects to have id == 3, like here:

```js
const data = [{
    "guid": "j5Dc9Z",
    "courses": [{
      "id": 3,
      "name": "foo"
    }]
  },
  {
    "guid": "a5gdfS",
    "courses": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "bar"
    }, {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "foo"
    }]
  }, {
    "guid": "jHab6i",
    "courses": [{
      "id": 7,
      "name": "foobar"
    }]
  }
];
const courses = [3];
const r = data
  .filter(d => d.courses.some(c => courses.includes(c.id)))
  .map(d => ({ ...d, courses: d.courses.filter(c => courses.includes(c.id))
  }));
console.log(r);
```

Comment: This one bring me id 1.I only wanna see the ids stored in courses array

Comment: Then you need to modify the resulting array again with map to filter out courses that are not in the approved list. I updated my solution. Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes works perfectly.Isn't there any way to achieve this easier?

Comment: Please define 'easier'. If you mean 'without filter or map functions', then you need to use for loops.

Comment: easier means with more less iterations

Comment: You can combine filter + map into one pass with `reduce` at the expense of readability

Comment: could you give an example?

Comment: You can read about combining map and filter here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34398279/map-and-filter-an-array-at-the-same-time

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find all items in the `data` that contain all of the ids found in the `const courses`, then you need to invert your filtering.

```js
const data = [
  {"guid": "j5Dc9Z", "courses": [{"id": 3, "name": "foo"}]},
  {"guid": "a5gdfS", "courses": [{"id": 1, "name": "bar"}, {"id": 3, "name": "foo"}]}, 
  {"guid": "jHab6i", "courses": [{"id": 7, "name": "foobar"}]}
];

const courses = [3];
const r = data.filter(d => courses.every(courseId => d.courses.find(({
  id
}) => courseId === id)));
console.log(r);
```