# Create an array of values from object based on key

Tags: javascript

If I have an object

```
post = {
title: "Title",
image_1: "1234",
image_2: "2345"
}
```

and I want to get an array:

```
["1234", "2345"]
```

This is how I filter attributes to be included in the array

```
Object.keys(post).filter(key =>
  key.includes("image")
);
```

and get an array of correct keys. How do I get values instead?

Comment: Use `Object.values` instead of `Object.keys`. Do you want a value based on the key or get all of the values from `includes` or something?

Comment: But I need to filter attributes based on key

Comment: Ight,
Use `Object.entries` and compare using the object's key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to just do your filter then map the object lookup:

```js
Object.keys(post)
    .filter(key => key.includes("image"))
    .map(key => post[key])
```

Or, use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get both keys and values:

```js
Object.entries(post)
    .filter(([key, value]) => key.includes("image"))
    .map(([key, value]) => value)
```

Or, with a ["filter and map" operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34398279/map-and-filter-an-array-at-the-same-time):

```js
Object.entries(post)
    .flatMap(([key, value]) => key.includes("image") ? [value] : [])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get a list of key-value pairs, and [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate over it:

```js
const post = {
  title: "Title",
  image_1: "1234",
  image_2: "2345"
};

const res = [];

Object.entries(post).forEach(([key,value]) => {
  if(key.includes("image")) res.push(value);
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const post = { title: "Title", image_1: "1234", image_2: "2345" };
const keys = Object.keys(post).filter(key => key.includes("image"));
const output = keys.map(key => post[key]);
console.log(output); // [ '1234', '2345' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `reduce` method on `Object.entries` and check if the key `startsWith` a specific string.

```js
const post = {
  title: "Title",
  image_1: "1234",
  image_2: "2345"
}

const result = Object
  .entries(post)
  .reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
    if (k.startsWith('image')) r.push(v);
    return r;
  }, [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Object.entries` to obtain entries, then filter those which starts with `image`:

```js
let post={title:"Title",image_1:"1234",image_2:"2345"};

let result = Object.entries(post)
.filter(e => e[0].startsWith('image'))
.flatMap(e => e[1])

console.log(result)
```