# return the value of the matching items in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, find

I have two arrays that I would like to compare and return a respective value of the ones that match.

Taking the 'id' variable as a reference, I want to return all the matching values of fastFood, but only the 'name'.

My expected result is to return Five Guys and KFC, but instead, it returns the entire object.

```
let id = ['1234'];
let fastFood = [
  {_id:'4391', name: "McDonalds"}, 
  {_id:'7654', name: "Burger King"}, 
  {_id:'8765', name: "Dominos"}, 
  {_id:'1234', name: "Five Guys"}, 
  {_id:'9876', name: "Subway"}, 
  {_id:'1234', name: "KFC"}
];


const findFastFood = ids.filter((item) => {
  if (item._id.indexOf(id) !== -1) {
    return item.name;
  }
});

console.log(findFastFood);
```

Comment: Can `id` array contain multiple entries?

Comment: There's no array with the name `ids`. `Array.prototype.filter()` has to return a boolean value (`true` or `false`) for _every_ element.

Comment: There is nothing like `ids`

Comment: And why `.indexOf()` for an id?

Comment: `item._id === id[0]` would do the job

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Map and filter an array at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34398279/map-and-filter-an-array-at-the-same-time)

Comment: `fastFood.flatMap(o => id.includes(o._id) ? [o.name] : []);`

Comment: @Ivar Why do you wrap the result in an array to then unwrap it again with `.flatMap()`? Why not `.filter().map()` or `.reduce()` to make the intention obvious?

Comment: @Andreas Good point. Didn't give it too much thought. I know there is a dupe somewhere that uses `.filter().map()` which was what I was looking for initially. Found this duplicate which seems to fit well. The `.reduce()` seems a bit over the top (comes across as not much more as a `.forEach` IMO), so took the second answer. But `fastFood.filter(({_id}) => id.includes(_id)).map(({name}) => name)` might be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```js
let id = ['1234'];
let fastFood = [{
    _id: '4391',
    name: "McDonalds"
  },
  {
    _id: '7654',
    name: "Burger King"
  },
  {
    _id: '8765',
    name: "Dominos"
  },
  {
    _id: '1234',
    name: "Five Guys"
  },
  {
    _id: '9876',
    name: "Subway"
  },
  {
    _id: '1234',
    name: "KFC"
  }
];


const findFastFood = fastFood.filter((item) => {
  if (id.indexOf(item._id) !== -1) {
    return item.name
  }

}).map(obj => obj.name);


console.log(findFastFood);
```