# How to join .map and .filter to filter and remove duplicate in object array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to join .map and .filter to filter and remove duplicate in object array?

I currently have to use two variables for this:

[Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyZhd.png)

See [code Sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-shadow-95rog?file=/src/App.js:202-767)

```
const arrayOne = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "João",
      city: {
        id: 1,
        name: "Rio de Janeiro"
      }
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Pedro",
      city: {
        id: 2,
        name: "Salvador"
      }
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Tiago",
      city: {
        id: 1,
        name: "Rio de Janeiro"
      }
    }
  ];

  const arrayTwo = arrayOne.map(function (item, index) {
    return item.city;
  });

  const arrayThree = arrayTwo.filter(
    (elem, index, arr) => index === arr.findIndex((t) => t.id === elem.id)
  );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your filter is just to remove duplicates consider creating a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) which simply overwrites all duplicate `city.id`s. This can then be converted back to an array, here using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) on the [`Map.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values).

```js
const arrayOne = [
  { id: 1, name: 'João', city: { id: 1, name: 'Rio de Janeiro' } },
  { id: 1, name: 'Pedro', city: { id: 2, name: 'Salvador' } },
  { id: 1, name: 'Tiago', city: { id: 1, name: 'Rio de Janeiro' } },
];

const arrayTwo = [...new Map(arrayOne.map(({ city }) => [city.id, city])).values()];

console.log(arrayTwo);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Just chain them together?

```
  const result = arrayOne.map(function (item, index) {
    return item.city;
  }).filter(
    (elem, index, arr) => index === arr.findIndex((t) => t.id === elem.id)
  );
```

If you mean that you want to map and filter at the same time, then you can use either `flatMap` or `reduce` as described in another Q/A: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34398349/211627

Comment: Thank you for your help!