# Retrieve and display individual object from array Javascipt/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose I have an array:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 9,
            "body": "This is the first body of text,
            "availability": "internal",
            "title": "Test",
            "posted_by": "Test"
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "body": "This is the second body of text",
            "availability": "internal",
            "title": "TEST2",
            "posted_by": "TEST2"
        },
}
```

My aim is to be able to print a specific "title" or "body" in my React app. Previously I had the data in JSON where I could simply use something like `data.title[0]` which would be `Test`.

Now I pull data using the following code:

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get(
        "API_KEY"
      )
      .then((res) => {
        let data = res.data
        this.setState({ data, loading: false });
        console.log(data)
      });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return <Loader />
    }

    else 
    return (
       this.state.data.data.map((item) => (
          <>
          <marquee direction="left" behaviour="scroll">
            <p key={item.id}>{item.body} </p>
            </marquee>
          </>
        ))
```

And I can't find a way to print specific "title" or "body" values, only every output in the array.

Currently my only idea is to use .slice() to manipulate the data the way I want, but this seems like a dirty way of fixing my issue.

Any advice/guidance greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question, answered in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34398279/map-and-filter-an-array-at-the-same-time?rq=1.

Comment: I think there is a typo error: have you tried to remove `)` after `this.state.data.data` in second return?

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito That is a typo, yes.

Comment: @FinlayJefferis so the problem is solved?

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito It wasn't present in m program, must have accidently added it while posting. This issue is not resolved

Comment: @FinlayJefferis another question: `console.log(data)` shows the object you posted or just the array of data?

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito It shows the array of data.

Comment: @FinlayJefferis so maybe we found the problem: you should write `this.state.data.map...` and not `this.state.data.data.map...`

Answer (score -1):

Unpacking fields from objects passed as a function parameter can do this.

```
const user = {
id: 42,
displayName: 'jdoe',
fullName: {
firstName: 'John',
lastName: 'Doe'
  }
};


function userId({id}) {
return id;
 }

function whois({displayName, fullName: {firstName: name}}) {
return `${displayName} is ${name}`;
 }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: https://sarangpatel.medium.com/destructuring-in-javascript-in-2-mins-8c883e77118d you copied also the title (by adding "can do this"). At least put the source link don't you think so?

Comment: There is no angry in my downvote. You copied a code that does not answer to OP forgetting to mention source. For me is not a good answer.