# Do not return null values in loop

Tags: javascript, loops, reactjs

How to return only the `image_url` when few `image_url` maybe `null`?

```
var lineItems = [
  {
    description: "Packaging",
    image_url: null,
    ...
  },
  {
    description: "T-Shirt",
    image_url: <the-url-link>,
    ...
  }
]
```

**In react:**

```
...

lineItems.map(function(line){
  if (line.description !== "Packaging") {
    var img = line.image_url;
  }
  console.log(img);
});

...
```

I keep getting `null` along with the web links in the console. How to grab only the `image_url` that has the links. "Packaging" will never have an image_url link; it'll always be `null`.

Comment: `filter` `null` values away?

Comment: do not use `map` in that way, it's just igrones your condition

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716818/using-array-map-to-filter-results-with-if-conditional

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen Just give me the links only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use a [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) here to do that for you.

```
const nonNulls = lineItems.filter(item => item.image_url !== null);
```

This will filter out all the non-null values into a variable.

Comment: This method is returning objects, I only need the string urls.

Comment: You need to chain `.map` to it like Emil used. `.map(obj => obj.image_url)` and you're good.

Comment: @SterlingArcher Nice, short and to the point. Carefull with `const` and [Lambda functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) though if compatibility is an issue.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var data = [
  {
    url: null
  },
  {
    url: null
  },
  {
    url: '123'
  },
  {
    url: null
  }
]
console.log(
  data.filter(function (a) {
    return a.url != null
  }).map(function (a) {
    return a.url
  })
)
```