# How to Remove Elements from Array of Objects based on some condition

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am facing a critical problem in angular

I have the following arrays

```
dataArray (3) [21, 21, 23]
```

and the below is actual Data from API

```
ViewData = [  
      {  
         "id":5,
         "name":"Private",
         "description":"",

      },
      {  
         "id":7,
         "name":"Semi Private",
         "description":"",

      },
      {  
         "id":8,
         "name":"laboratory",
         "description":"",

      },
      {  
         "id":15,
         "name":"Test",

      },
      {  
         "id":16,
         "name":"Testss",
         "description":null,

      },
      {  
         "id":18,
         "name":"TestSan",
         "description":null,

      },
      {  
         "id":21,
         "name":"TestBBB",
         "description":"test",

      },
      {  
         "id":23,
         "name":"TestOne",
         "description":null,

      },
      {  
         "id":2,
         "name":"Standard ward",
         "description":"",
         "sharing":4,
         "set_value":2
      }
   ]
```

I have to process ViewData (2nd array) after processing ViewData should not contain JSON Objects which ids are present in dataArray(I mean if the any id of ViewData is equal to id which is in DataArray i want to remove that JSON Object from View Data)
   (Out put should be like below )

```
ViewData = [  
      {  
         "id":5,
         "name":"Private",
         "description":"",

      },
      {  
         "id":7,
         "name":"Semi Private",
         "description":"",

      },
      {  
         "id":8,
         "name":"laboratory",
         "description":"",

      },
      {  
         "id":15,
         "name":"Test",

      },
      {  
         "id":16,
         "name":"Testss",
         "description":null,

      },
      {  
         "id":18,
         "name":"TestSan",
         "description":null,

      },

      {  
         "id":2,
         "name":"Standard ward",
         "description":"",
         "sharing":4,
         "set_value":2
      }
   ]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using array map to filter results with if conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716818/using-array-map-to-filter-results-with-if-conditional)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can make use of [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method for this

```
const arryids = {1,3,9};//remove id array 
const filteredarray = this.ViewData.filter(d=> !array.includes(d.id));
this.ViewData= filteredarray;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `filter`

```
ViewData = ViewData.filter( s => !dataArray.includes( s.id ) )
```

Comment: This was helpful for my scenario to get rid of objects from an array according to conditions from another entries.

Answer (score 0):

Using `filter` with combination `includes`. `filter` will return a new array based on the condition. Those items for which the condition returns true, will be added in the output array.

```js
const ids = [21, 23];
const viewData = [  
      {  
         "id":5,
         "name":"Private",
         "description":"",

      },
      {  
         "id":7,
         "name":"Semi Private",
         "description":"",

      },
      {  
         "id":8,
         "name":"laboratory",
         "description":"",

      },
      {  
         "id":15,
         "name":"Test",

      },
      {  
         "id":16,
         "name":"Testss",
         "description":null,

      },
      {  
         "id":18,
         "name":"TestSan",
         "description":null,

      },
      {  
         "id":21,
         "name":"TestBBB",
         "description":"test",

      },
      {  
         "id":23,
         "name":"TestOne",
         "description":null,

      },
      {  
         "id":2,
         "name":"Standard ward",
         "description":"",
         "sharing":4,
         "set_value":2
      }
   ];
   
const filteredData = viewData.filter(item => !ids.includes(item.id));

console.log(filteredData);
```

Comment: Thank you very much all for your support, it is working fine      and  feeling very happy i am new to JavaScript

Answer (score -1):

```
if(condition){
var key = "your_key";
delete json[key];
}
```

Comment: your code removes an item in an key-value array. The OP wants to remove an item from an array of objects (each one is a key-value array)...there is a difference