# Using reduce you need to create a new array that contains all the names from the initial array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

i have this array

```
const names = [
  { name: 'Anna' },
  { num: 27 },
  { name: 'Valeria', age: 20},
  { secondname: 'Wilson' },
  { age: 12, name: 'Max' },
  { weight:'50kg', height: '172cm', name: 'Nick' }
]
```

using reduce i need to create new array that contains all names from initial array
i made like this, but i think it is bad

```
let allNames = names.reduce((previousValue, names) =>{
  return previousValue + names.name},[])
console.log(allNames)
```

i did

````
   allName.push(ar.name);
 
   return allName;
 }, []);
 
 console.log(names);```
````

Comment: No need for reduce: `const out = names.map(obj => obj.name || 'No name')`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

#### `Array.reduce()`

You have multiple options. You can use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to merge them all into one array. You just need to check if `name` is defined.

```js
names.reduce((allNames, person) => {
  if (person.name) {
    return [...allNames, person.name];
  }

  return allNames;
}, []);
```

#### `Array.forEach()`

Same for [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
const allNames = [];

names.forEach((person) => {
  if (person.name) {
    allNames.push(person.name);
  }
});

allNames;
```

Instead, I would recommend using [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove all people without a name and map ([`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)) over them, to just return the names.
In terms of runtime, this would require you to loop twice over the array, but I think this is way more readable

#### `Array.filter` / `Array.map`

```js
names
  .filter((person) => person.name)
  .map((person) => person.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) by including a check for objects that don't have the name property and an empty array as initial value:

```js
const names = [
  { name: 'Anna' },
  { num: 27 },
  { name: 'Valeria', age: 20},
  { secondname: 'Wilson' },
  { age: 12, name: 'Max' },
  { weight:'50kg', height: '172cm', name: 'Nick' }
] 

const reduceResult = names.reduce((previous, current) => {
  if(current.name)
  {
    previous.push(current.name);
  }
  
  return previous;
}
,
[]);

console.log(reduceResult);

/*
[
  "Anna",
  "Valeria",
  "Max",
  "Nick"
]
*/
```

Using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), you will have undefined for objects that don't have a name property:

```js
const mapResult = names.map(x => x.name);

console.log(mapResult);

/*
[
  "Anna",
  undefined,
  "Valeria",
  undefined,
  "Max",
  "Nick"
]
*/
```

[filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) + [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) can also be used but performance talking reduce is a [better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716818/using-array-map-to-filter-results-with-if-conditional/47877054#47877054) choice.

```js
const filterMapResult = names.filter(({name}) => !!name).map(x => x.name);

console.log(filterMapResult);

/*
[
  "Anna",
  "Valeria",
  "Max",
  "Nick"
]
*/
```